# Money borrowed in bank account one month before applying for Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen, spain

I borrowed a considerable amount from my friend before applying to Schengen visa. How can I explain it in my visa application cover letter about it? What if I return it back to my friend and then get a bank statement would it will be fine?

I made a mistake by getting money in my account, how can I get myself out of this situation?

Comment: In the explanations write honestly why you borrowed the money and what you are going to use it for. If you do not need it for your travels you will be alright. It is the overall money situation they are interested in. If you do need that money for your travel, you might reconsider going at all. Travel on borrowed money is not good, can get you in trouble later.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for the response. I thought I will need it a month ago but now I don't think so, and I have all the travel itinerary and just to be on safe side I am using my Brother as Sponsor(so visa won't get rejected). But only concern is that, would this extra money I borrowed before inquiring the whole process would effect? And I read that consulate check the flow of money in general and in my case the flow has been adulterated. So I am worried if it might get rejected due my stupidy. :(

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this excellent answer about demonstrating your general financial standing [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105) If you did not need the loan from your friend to satisfy these points then possibly providing an explanation about the loan will suffice. If not, then your best option would be to wait until your financial history is ‘clean’ before applying for a visa. Having your brother as a sponsor does not guarantee that your application will be approved - you will still need to demonstrate your financial standing.

Comment: Well, I did explain the loan situation in my cover letter as it was not required for my traveling and also submitted all the documents from whom I took the loan. Finally, I received my passport with approved Visa. Thank you for commenting earlier and clearing up things :)